# In Java LinkedList source code, why the unlinkFirst function should have a param pointing to the first node?

Tags: java

Some part of the source code in LinkedList, which contains all of the reference to the unlinkFirst function:

```
    /**
     * Pointer to first node.
     * Invariant: (first == null && last == null) ||
     *            (first.prev == null && first.item != null)
     */
    transient Node<E> first;

    private E unlinkFirst(Node<E> f) {
        // assert f == first && f != null;
        final E element = f.item;
        final Node<E> next = f.next;
        f.item = null;
        f.next = null; // help GC
        first = next;
        if (next == null)
            last = null;
        else
            next.prev = null;
        size--;
        modCount++;
        return element;
    }

    public E removeFirst() {
        final Node<E> f = first;
        if (f == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return unlinkFirst(f);
    }
    public E poll() {
        final Node<E> f = first;
        return (f == null) ? null : unlinkFirst(f);
    }
    public E pollFirst() {
        final Node<E> f = first;
        return (f == null) ? null : unlinkFirst(f);
    }
```

I think that using a non-param function like this:

```
    private E unlinkFirst() {
        Node<E> f = first;
        final E element = f.item;
        final Node<E> next = f.next;
        f.item = null;
        f.next = null; // help GC
        first = next;
        if (next == null)
            last = null;
        else
            next.prev = null;
        size--;
        modCount++;
        return element;
    }
```

is easier to read and more convinient to call.So what's the intention to write like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method for removing the first Node from a List can be implemented to be parameterless, and duplicating the reference to the first node might seem redundant.

I think it's done for the purpose of consistency, to make internal all methods which are meant for Node-removal adhere with same stylistic patterns.

Method `romove()` delegates to the auxiliary method `unlink(Node<E> x)` (*in this case the link to the target node is required*), and similarly `romoveFirst()` delegates to `unlinkFirst(Node<E> f)`, `removeLast()` delegates to `unlinkLast(Node<E> l)`.

All three `unlink`, `unlinkFirst` and `unlinkLast` are meant to be used internally, all are implemented to dial with only *non-null* nodes. There's no necessity `removeFirst` and `unlinkLast` to expect the node as an argument, it's rather a stylistic choice.

Also, as *@Mark Rotteveel* has pointed out in the comments, this might be done in order to make the calls of auxiliary methods `unlinkFirst` and `unlinkLast` to be eligible for being optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: Probably it is an optimization, as the caller already has to store the node in a local variable and then push it on the call-stack for the method call (which I guess might be optimized to a single stack item). This avoids having to copy the field to a local variable again in `unlinkFirst`, and also avoids the need for another null-check.